# DispatchQueue Main async reference problem. (Reference gone)

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, amazon-cognito, dispatch-queue

I have a function for getting user session. I successfully get the session. But inside the DispatchQueue i lose task object (task:AWSTask< AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession >).

Before DispatchQueue it is not null but in the dispatch DispatchQueue it is null. Some how i am losing the reference.

What is the best way to get and object reference from outside of the DispatchQueue. (I dont want to create a general variable in the class.)
**BTW this is not happening all the time.**

```
var pool:AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool

override init(){
    pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")
    super.init()
}

func getUserPool() -> AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool {
    return pool
}

func getUserSession(completition: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    let user = pool.currentUser()!
    let task = user.getSession()
           task.continueWith{ (task:AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession>) in
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    if(task.result != nil && task.error == nil)
                    {
                        /*
                         There are some calculations here

                         */

                        completition()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `DispatchQueue.main.async { [task] in`?

Comment: You should hold a strong reference to your class instance which you are calling from the parent.

Comment: can you provide the implementation of `pool.currentUser()` and `user.getSession()`and can you say if you are holding `pool` variable?

Comment: It's not possible for `task` to be nil (I assume you mean nil; there is no "null" in this code). `task` is not Optional inside the closure. How are you determining that this is your problem?

Comment: @RobNapier like you said task is not optional, but somehow i am getting nil. I assume i am losing the reference when transferring object between threads.

Comment: How are you determining that the task is nil? It cannot be nil. Why do you think it is? (If it is, there's a compiler problem here, or AWSTask is an ObjC type that has incorrect annotations, but that seems even less likely given it's generic.)